# ChromaDB Management

Tags: large-language-model, chromadb

Is there an efficient way of managing ChromaDB instances in place - specifically using metadata to delete documents?  Inserts/upserts are supported.  Deletes by collection are supported, but I can't find much in their API for deleting specific documents or sources based on specific data elements... I'm mostly focused on metadata attributes.  Essentially deleting all docs from a source in a single query.

I currently just use DuckDB or the ChromaAPI to uery the database, excluding the sources or documents I'd like to exclude.  Then just re-create a new database without the sources/docs I don't want included.  It's fine, but doesn't feel right :)

Any tips would help.  Not looking for code, but there isn't much on their website about deleting anything other than collections.  If this is a limitation that's fine, I'm not being killed by this limitation, but if there is a better way I'm all ears.

Thanks,

Mark